# How can we display multiple tabs in ionic 2 app?

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic2

Hi all I am new to ionic 2,How can we use multiple tabs in my app,

- My plunker for reference :- [My Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7Ld2jA3qA704PqIbxg2K?p=preview) , is there any possibility to use multiple tabs?
- in plunker `tabs-page` we have used two `ion-tabs` but only one tab is displaying, another one tab is not `visible`.
- what we exactly looking for, we just need to use `multiple tabs` and multiple tabs are need to be `visible` in the page...
- we don't know where we did the mistake and how it's works , is there any possible to use multiple tabs in a app...

My `ion-tabs` code:-

```
<ion-tabs>
   <ion-tab tabIcon="apps" [root]="tab3Root"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>

<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Tab 1" tabIcon="pulse"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Tab 2" tabIcon="pulse"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

- the above two tabs are need to be visible

**In plunker this below ion-tab is not displaying**:-

```
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab tabIcon="apps" [root]="tab3Root"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

- if any one know the solution please help us, and update the plunker as well to know the exact solution thanks...

Comment: Please see this example..
http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/odqCz

Comment: thanks for your comment @ sahil...i think this `codepen` is ionic one, we are looking for ionic 2...

Comment: If you can make a fiddle of your code that will be great.. Did you check this- https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/tabs/Tabs/  ??

Comment: The problem most probably is one tab being on top of other. So use css to push it down. I use multiple tabs and it works fine ( but there some problems associated with it . ``Segments`` are a good alternative. ). My tabs are placed on top and bottom resp.

Comment: @sahil  thanks for your valuable comments will check and update you.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It Can done by using CSS and making the `visible`. Follow below code and [plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/VpQt8cpX15qCHjKr2t0b?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<ion-tabs tabs-only>
 <ion-tab tabIcon="apps" [root]="tab3Root"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>

<ion-tabs tabs-only2 >
 <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Tab 1" tabIcon="pulse"></ion-tab>
 <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Tab 2" tabIcon="pulse"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

**CSS**

```
ion-tabs[tabs-only] .tabbar {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    height: auto;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 111;
    height: 85px;
}

ion-tabs[tabs-only] {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    contain: none;
    top: 85%;
}
```